# trying to create a directory in my bitnami odoo 9 stack through filezilla on my google cloud compute engine but getting a permission denied message

Tags: ftp, google-cloud-platform, add-on, bitnami, odoo-9

Hi All on stackoverflow,

I have been trying to figure out how to create a directory in my bitnami odoo 9 stack through filezilla on my google cloud compute engine but getting a permission denied message when trying to create a new directory in location:

/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-9.0rc20160209-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons

as i wish to see my new addon in my odoo 9 apps backend system.

Here are the steps I followed to get filezilla access, which I now have but really struggling with creating a new directory in this location or even changing the addons directory file permissions is giving me a permission denied message.

Anyway steps I followed were mostly from this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ssfE6ODpak but there were some slight differences towards the end i enountered.

from my sdk gcloud window I got the message (please note I have entered in some XX as I dont want to publish data that would open access to any of my system:

---

This tool needs to create the directory [C:\Users\James.ssh] before
being able to generate SSH keys.

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y

Updated [h.t.t.p.s.://www.googleapis(dot)com/compute/v1/projects/XXXXXXXXXXX].
The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
think it is.
The server's rsa2 key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa XXXX 2f:XX:ec:XX:c1:e3:XX:5e:XX:0c:XX:76:XX:48:XX:f9
If you trust this host, enter "y" to add the key to
PuTTY's cache and carry on connecting.
If you want to carry on connecting just once, without
adding the key to the cache, enter "n".
If you do not trust this host, press Return to abandon the
connection.

### Store key in cache? (y/n) y

At this point a putty window opened displaying the following:

---

Using username "James".
Authenticating with public key "LENOVO-PC\James@Lenovo-PC"
Linux odoo-1-vm 3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u3~bpo70+1 (2016-01-19) x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
       **_ _ _                   _
      | _ |*) |* _ _  __ _ _ __ (_)
      | _ \ |  _| ' / *` | '  \| |
      |***/*|_*|*|*|__,*|*|*|*|_|

*** Welcome to the Bitnami Odoo 9.0-3**              
   **Bitnami Wiki:   wiki.bitnami(dt)com/**      
   **Bitnami Forums: community.bitnami(dt)com/ ***

James@odoo-1-vm:~$ sudo chown -R daemon:daemon /opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-9.0rc20160209-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons
James@odoo-1-vm:~$ sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
Syntax OK
/opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd stopped
Syntax OK
/opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd started at port 80

---

As you can see from the above I followed a sudo chown command which I found on docs.bitnami(dot)com/google/apps/odoo/#HowtoinstallapluginonOdoo?

But I am still getting the permission denied message when trying to copy a directory from my local machine or create a directory using filezilla.

Many thanks for any help in advance and many apologies for my ignorance in this subject.

Kind regards,

James

P.S. I am sure I am not the only person suffering with this problem
P.P.S. I did a good thorough search but apologies again if this question has already been asked.

Comment: I figured it out! Issue had 2do with Owner/Group permissions.  I was logging in with my username = James Using the SSH window in google cloud i changed to root user & ran 2 commands to change file Owner/Group to my user.  ## Step 1 ## change SSH to root = command sudo su  ## Step 2 ## run command: chown -R --from=daemon James /path/here  this changed Owner from daemon to James in my specified path   ## Step 3 ## run command: chown -R --from=:daemon :James /some/directory  this changed the Group from daemon to James in my specified path. I then got sftp access to enable me to create directories

Comment: I really hope this helps lots of people as I have seen tons of forums asking a similar question and very little if any help and advice on what to do to fix this issue.  I suspect this is probably not the best way but certainly works as a work around!!